# Use Relationship column value as property

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a one to many relation. They all have a unique column ( besides ID ). After running the query, Im trying to access the relation results using that unique column value.

> $parent->rrelation->unique_column_value

So a sample table could be: Table: meta_value

```
| ID |     KEY    |   VALUE   |
| 1  |    name    |   John    |
| 2  | last_name  |   Doe     |
| 3  |   source   |   Media   |
```

So, if query call is

```
$entries = tax::with('meta_value')->get()
```

I would like to access the relation values this way:

```
$entries->meta_value->name;
$entries->meta_value->last_name;
$entries->meta_value->source
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a one to many relation, you will retrieve all of the matching models. You then need to loop through your entries to be able to access the different meta_value fields.

```
$entries = tax::with('meta_value')->get();

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $name      = $entry->meta_value->name;
    $last_name = $entry->meta_value->last_name;
    $source    = $entry->meta_value->source;
}
```

Please see for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading